# Does an eGPU increase performance of Lightroom Classic on 2018 13" rMBP?

Tags: lightroom, macintosh, performance

Using a the 2018 13" Retina MacBook Pro for Lightroom Classic.

Would adding an external GPU increase performance of the Lightroom Classic application? And if so, which modules/parts get increased performance?

Comment: I'd say this is too specific a question. As tech changes rapidly. Just "Is there a performance benefit" for light room to having a dedicated GPU vs integrated might be better. But I also can't escape the feeling that buying a dock + GPU would cost more than buying a decent desktop with the right components or even a better laptop, rather than the Macbook + dock + decent GPU.